# Windows 10 File Explorer aka Windows Explorer, keeps launching itself

Tags: windows-explorer

Windows 10 File Explorer aka Windows Explorer, keeps launching itself, sometimes every few seconds sometimes 10 -15 minutes apart. minimising doesn't help as it pops up again.
Very annoying in the middle of an online game, just plain annoying the rest of the time. Any ideas how to stop/fix this? Many thanks.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut is Win E to open Explorer, are you hitting that combination possibly, or does your mouse have a button set to open Explorer?

Comment: No not using that combination. It can launch when I'm reading a page or not even using the PC, I come back and there it is.

Comment: Does this happen within a minimal boot configuration.  By minimal configuration I do not mean "safe mode".

Comment: Does this occur with [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135)?

Comment: Have you scanned for virusses and malware? Sounds like an infection.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by minimal boot Ramhound. or Cleanboot Michael D. I've run full scans LPChip but nothing coming up. Thanks